# bootstrap 5 js correctly added to wordpress but some components dosen't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

First of all I want to mention that I code my template static and everything works fine.
When I want to go dynamic on wordpress use bootstrap 5; enqueue styles and scripts with the codes below.
all the bootstrap files add to site (cuse I get view page source in chrome) but some components like carousel and dropedown not working.
(wordpress template is pure and I don't use any plugin cusing interference)

any idea whats wrong?

```html
function theme_assets()
{
    //styles
    wp_register_style('style-CSS', get_stylesheet_uri(), 'all');
    wp_register_style('bootstrap-CSS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css', array(), 'all');
    wp_register_style('owl-CSS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.carousel.css', array(), 'all');
    wp_register_style('main-CSS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css', array(), 'all');
    //scripts

    wp_register_script('bootstrap.bundle-JS', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'), array(), '5.0', true);
    wp_register_script('bootstrap-JS', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'), array(), '5.0', true);
    wp_register_script('script-JS', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/script.js'), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    
    //enqueue
    wp_enqueue_style('style-CSS');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-CSS');
    wp_enqueue_style('owl-CSS');
    wp_enqueue_style('main-CSS');

    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.bundle-JS');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-JS');
    wp_enqueue_script('script-JS');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_assets');
```

ut modal works. seems so strange. anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is caused by loading 2 versions of the Bootstrap script.  The "bundle" version is the one you need.  Try removing "bootstrap.min.js" You might also consider removing Owl Carousel because it is very old. You could remove jQuery too since it seems only included for Owl Carousel.  Bootstrap includes a carousel component, as  you probably already know.

Comment: I ussed things you said before. nothing chnges. owl is greate for slider. problem is when everything is static nothing wrong. but in wordpress although all js are enqueue corectly and added to site some component not working.

Comment: The problem is definitely caused by loading 2 Bootstrap scripts as shown in your code. In tests, the dropdown failed completely and the other components worked, but with strange behavior.  All components worked normally when only the Bootstrap bundle was loaded.  See [Test 1](https://jsfiddle.net/7v9yjs1h/show) and [Test 2](https://jsfiddle.net/7v9yjs1h/1/show).

Comment: after delete bootstrap.min.js nothing changes. modal works. but dropdown and carousel doesn't

Comment: You have multiple problems.  This second problem is with your html.  You have coded the carousel using Bootstrap 4 class names.  The class names have changed in Bootstrap 5.  For example, data-slide is now data-bs-slide and data-ride is now data-bs-ride.  see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/#via-data-attributes  I did not look at the other components on the page, but it seems likely that they might also use the wrong class names.

Comment: oh, thanks man. I always search in google bootstrap carousel and not check the version. little big mistake!

Comment: The change of class name cause problems for many people and questions about it are common here.  So no worries.